# Running an AC sweep in PSPice

Tags: pspice

I'm trying to do an AC sweep of the following circuit:
[image]

But I'm getting the following error:

```
*Analysis directives: 
.AC DEC 5 0 1000000
----------$
ERROR(ORPSIM-16103): Invalid value
.OPTIONS ADVCONV
.PROBE64 V(alias(*)) I(alias(*)) W(alias(*)) D(alias(*)) NOISE(alias(*)) 
.INC "..\SCHEMATIC1.net" 



 **** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
 * source ECE209LEC
 C_C4         N00807 N00815  0.11u  TC=0,0 
 R_R4         N00807 N00963  1000 TC=0,0 
 C_C2         0 N00889  40n  TC=0,0 
 R_R2         N00791 N00889  1k TC=0,0 
 C_C1         N00791 N00799  0.26u  TC=0,0 
 V_V1         N00873 0  
 +SIN 0 10 1000 0 0 0
 R_R1         N00873 N00791  1k TC=0,0 
 C_C3         0 N00963  90n  TC=0,0 
 E_U1         N01832 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N00889,N00799)*1E6,-15V,+15V)}
 E_U2         N01817 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N00963,N00815)*1E6,-15V,+15V)}
 R_R3         N01832 N00807  1000 TC=0,0 
 ** Floating/unmodeled pin fixups **
 R__UC0001   N01817  0   {1/GMIN}

 **** RESUMING freq.cir ****
 .END
```

For the start frequency I chose 0 and the end frequency 1000000.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You can't start an AC simulation at 0Hz since this would be DC.

Comment: As Mario says, it doesn't make sense to put 0Hz. In fact, you can have an infinite amount of decade between 0Hz and 1MHz (0.000001, 0.00001, etc.).

Comment: @lucas92 Thank you! I was finally able to fix it thanks to you, guys.

Comment: Why doesn't DC make sense if it's a linear sweep?

Answer (score 2):

Your start point for an AC sweep cannot be 0. It must be a greater value than 0, otherwise it would be DC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141052)

Comment: @laptop2d Yes it does provide an answer, even a correct answer for the question. It's in terrible shape and could use some editing, but it does not fall under the "not an answer" category.

Comment: Couldn't this have very well been a comment?